# Default Powershell Terminal is 7.2 but scripts run as Powershell 5.1

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

Notice in my VS Code, a fresh terminal, the very first line indicates it is properly defaulted to Powershell 7.2.2 - just as I believe it should.

But then in this same screenshot, the first script I run (which has a command to print out the powershell version) it shows the `PSVersion` is `5.1.19041.1320`

[image: vs code default terminal screenshot]

Here's all my powershell specific VSCode entries from `settings.json`

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "MyPowerShell_7": {
          "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
          "args": ["-NoProfile"]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "MyPowerShell_7",
    "powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths": [
        {
            "exePath": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
            "versionName": "MyPowerShell_7"
        }
    ],
    "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "MyPowerShell_7",
```

Why why why is it so hard to run the `Test-Json` cmdlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found an answer [here on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/i0re5e/installed_powershell_7_but_5_still_the_default/)

I didn't know that 5.1 and 7 are side-by-side and have different ways to invoke each application

So, if I change my command from `powershell` to `pwsh` I get the right result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you have a PowerShell or pwsh terminal open (Which you have here) you should call your script directly and it will be executed in that host.

So instead of

```
PS C:\>pwsh -file './scripts/ps/experiment.ps1'`
```

you should call

```
PS C:\>./scripts/ps/experiment.ps1
```

The way you are calling your scripts will launch a new host, run the script and then terminate.